# Azure Synapse Failure

Tags: azure-synapse

Using the below code I am trying to copy the data from this code into a dedicated table. The data is coming from a Parquet that I need to alter before loading it into the table. I get the below error.

Operation on target Move InvItemDist to DP failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side.
ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'.,},],'

Code:

```
    SELECT 
    A.[NDC]
    , A.[ProductID]
    , A.[Customer_Site]
    , A.[ZipFileName]

   FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT
                [NDC]
                , [ProductID]
                , [Customer_Site]
                , LEFT
                    (
                        SUBSTRING([ZipFileName], NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', [ZipFileName], NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', [ZipFileName]), 0) + 1), 0) + 1, LEN([ZipFileName]))
                        , LEN(SUBSTRING([ZipFileName], NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', [ZipFileName], NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', [ZipFileName]), 0) + 1), 0) + 1, LEN([ZipFileName]))) - 4
                    ) AS [ZileFileOrder]
                , [ZipFileName]
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [NDC], [ProductID], [Customer_Site] 
                        ORDER BY LEFT
                    (
                        SUBSTRING([ZipFileName], NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', [ZipFileName], NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', [ZipFileName]), 0) + 1), 0) + 1, LEN([ZipFileName]))
                        , LEN(SUBSTRING([ZipFileName], NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', [ZipFileName], NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', [ZipFileName]), 0) + 1), 0) + 1, LEN([ZipFileName]))) - 4
                    ) DESC) AS UN

        FROM
            OPENROWSET(
                BULK 'https://stonexiacctolleson3154ba.dfs.core.windows.net/fs-tolleson/InvItemDist - Fact/2022/06/15/*.parquet',
                FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
            ) AS [result]
    ) AS A
WHERE A.[UN] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

> OPENROWSET() is currently not supported in synapse dedicated pool.

You can raise a feature request from the portal.

Use **External file format** to access the data from the files. You can refer to this Microsoft document to [create an External file format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop#create-external-file-format) to read the parquet files

Comment: My Source is Serverless and and my Sink is Dedicated